# Excel data connection query detecting syntax error

Tags: sql, excel, odbc

I'm attempting to put together a database query to our company database, and I'm having a hell of a time getting this damned odbc connection to cooperate with me. I finally managed to get a very basic parameter in the query without it returning an error (even though similar queries while connected through putty work without an issue), and have since tried to make one of the parameters more dynamic. I put a text string representing a date into a cell of my excel workbook, and am trying to use that as the reference for the searching parameter. However, when I do it returns an error. Here is the query:

```
select * from rtprice where hedgedate = [FEC Database$B18]
```

When I attempt to run the query, I get a returned error that says something like this

```
Syntax error in line 1:

encountered: [
expected: CASE, CAST, EXISTS, FALSE, etc etc
```

Are brackets not the correct syntax for a dynamic query parameter? Please help me

Comment: Can you please provide more information regarding the query, the name of the workbook, etc? Also, can you post more of your code? I do this all the time, so hope I can help. You can't reference a workbook like you are trying to, but I can't tell you how to do it without more info.

Comment: @Kyle This is through the workbook connections window that you get to in the Data tab in excel. So far, that is the only line of the query. its simply an ODBC connection that I set up using the data connection wizard, and then I changed the definition to have that query I posted. The workbook is named "FEC Prototype", and this data connection should already be within that notebook. The reference I am making is to a sheet within that notebook.

Comment: My apologies, I saw odbc and assumed query through VBA. Shows you what assuming does... :)

Comment: Should I be trying to do the dynamic query using VBA? I looked at that first but then I would need to figure out how to make a procedure on our company database server, right? Or can I just write the query normally and have VBA sub in the dynamic info? I saw the procedure made with the parameters passed to it, as you would any other function you define.

Comment: I tend to use VBA paired with ADO (others prefer DAO) to query databases. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/3578/working-with-ado#t=201701252225572622941) may be of interest. There is no need to setup stored procs to do this, you can simply put in the query. Parameterized procedures are more secure, however.

Comment: The remote database doesn't get the value from your Excel cell; it's just getting that literal text, `[FEC Database$B18]`, which it doesn't know how to interpret. Your question as written is an example of the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem); I suggest rewriting it with an eye to the bigger picture and your overall goals.

Comment: @TallTed I just need a query that can be dynamic... from what I found online some people have suggested syntax like this. I'm not trying to be rude, but vague philosophies on problem solving aren't going to help me.

Comment: I suggested the [rewrite in order to get the answer you need](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Maybe start with "I need to run a dynamic query, based on the content of a spreadsheet cell, from MS Excel {version?}, against {DBMS?}." That said, this may not be the site for such [a broad question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).